# Is time complexity saved if you save a Map's values as an array, instead of iterating over the map?

Tags: javascript, hashmap

I am using a map in JS to store the number of occurrences of an element, but I am not sure whether I should store the element *also* as a value in order to access it quicker. For reference, I am solving Single Number II on LeetCode (https://leetcode.com/problems/single-number-ii/).

```
var singleNumber = function(nums) {
    let map = new Map();
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        if (!map.has(nums[i])){
            map.set(nums[i], [nums[i], 1])
        } else {
            map.set(nums[i], [nums[i], map.get(nums[i][1]) + 1])
        }
    }
    let res = [...map.values()].filter((x)=> x[1] === 1);
    return res[0][0]
};
```

Here is what I thought of doing: storing each key also as a value, so that I could easily filter them and grab the key. The other option is to iterate through the entire map:

```
class Solution {
  public int singleNumber(int[] nums) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int num : nums)
      hashmap.put(num, hashmap.getOrDefault(num, 0) + 1);

    for (int k : hashmap.keySet())
      if (hashmap.get(k) == 1) return k;
    return -1;
  }
}
```

The above solution is from the LeetCode solution page.

Which one of these methods is preferred? Is one better than the other regarding time complexity?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the lowest time complexity is desired, there are exceptions though. Then, we'd look into memory complexity.

For this question, bitwise algorithm is preferred because it'll reduce the memory complexity to constant (`O(1)`).

#### JavaScript

```
var singleNumber = function(nums) {
    let seenOnce = 0
    let seenTwice = 0

    for (let num of nums) {
      seenOnce = ~seenTwice & (seenOnce ^ num);
      seenTwice = ~seenOnce & (seenTwice ^ num);
    }

    return seenOnce;
};
```

#### Java

```
class Solution {
    public int singleNumber(int[] nums) {
        int res = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            int sum = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++)
                if (((nums[j] >> i) & 1) == 1) {
                    sum++;
                    sum %= 3;
                }

            if (sum != 0)
                res |= sum << i;
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

Here is a LeetCode's solution with comments:

```
class Solution {
  public int singleNumber(int[] nums) {
    int seenOnce = 0, seenTwice = 0;

    for (int num : nums) {
      // first appearence: 
      // add num to seen_once 
      // don't add to seen_twice because of presence in seen_once

      // second appearance: 
      // remove num from seen_once 
      // add num to seen_twice

      // third appearance: 
      // don't add to seen_once because of presence in seen_twice
      // remove num from seen_twice
      seenOnce = ~seenTwice & (seenOnce ^ num);
      seenTwice = ~seenOnce & (seenTwice ^ num);
    }

    return seenOnce;
  }
}
```

The above algorithm runs at `O(N)` time and `O(1)` space.

#### Python using Counter

```
class Solution:
    def singleNumber(self, nums):        
        return collections.Counter(nums).most_common(len(nums))[-1][0]
```

#### C++

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

struct Solution {
    static std::int_fast32_t singleNumber(const std::vector<int>& nums) {
        std::vector<int> num_vect(32);

        const std::size_t length = nums.size();
        std::int_fast32_t i;
        std::int_fast32_t j;
        std::int_fast32_t num;

        for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            num = nums[i];

            for (j = 31; j >= 0; --j) {
                num_vect[j] += num & 1;
                num >>= 1;

                if (!num) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        std::int_fast32_t single_num = 0;

        for (j = 31; j >= 0; --j) {
            num = num_vect[j] % 3;

            if (num) {
                single_num += 1 << (31 - j);
            }
        }

        return single_num;
    }
};
```

By the way, you should not use sorting at all for this question, because it'll increase the time complexity from `O(N)` to `O(N Log N)`.

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/single-number-ii/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

Comment: Uh, this is a javascript question?

Answer (score 0):

> Here is what I thought of doing: storing each key also as a value

No, you should not do that. It just creates unnecessary tuple objects taking up memory unnecessarily. Keys are available easily enough when accessing a map.

> So that I could easily filter them and grab the key. [Without] iterat[ing] through the entire map

You already *are* iterating through the entire map, that's what `[...map.values()]` does. In fact you should not do that, as you don't need to iterate through the *entire* map and filter for *all* values that match the condition, you only want to find the first and break the iteration once you got it.

The proper way to iterate through a JavaScript `Map` when you need both key and value is by using its [`.entries()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries), which is also the [default iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/@@iterator):

```
function singleNumber(nums) {
    const  map = new Map();
    for (const num of nums) {
        const val = map.has(num) ? map.get(num) : 0;
        map.set(num, val + 1)
    }
    for (let [key, val] of map) {
        if (val === 1) {
            return key;
        }
    }
    return -1; // or null or undefined or something
}
```